# Is anyone using Sinch SMS for verification? I can't seem to get any sms on phone.

Tags: web, sinch, sinch-verification

I just signed up for sinch and right away i was offered $2 credit( use for testing). I put my number and hit submit( but never received any sms) I even downloaded their javascript example app in which I tried to send verification code after adding $5 to my sinch account. Still nothing. Anyone ran into this issue. I tried twitter digits and it works every time.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to hear that, mail in to support and sate your account mail you signed up for Sinch and we can refund you right away, also if you could supply your phone number you tried to verify I will look in to what went wrong trying to verify that number.

Comment: It seems as though the phone carrier might be the problem. I tried on multiple phones but they were all using republic wireless it didnt work. Tried on a google voice number, it worked right away

Comment: I had been in contact with a sinch rep, after nearly a week I received the following reply:                                                                               `"We were not able to find anything out of the ordinary.  Unfortunately it may just be that there is an issue with your specific number and we are not able to support sending SMS to it.

While rare this may happen occasionally."`